# which image type is equivalent to 5

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I wrote the below code to check if the type of the image "RGB,BGR or any other type". when i ran the code i received value equals to 5, and i also checked the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getType()) but still i do not know which type is equivalent to number 5!

please let me know how to know the equivalent image type to 5.

**code**:

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File imgFile = new File("c:\\img.jpg");
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(imgFile);

    System.out.println(bi.getType());
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the getType() documentation you provided led me to the image type listings in "See Also". That led to the [Constant Field Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR) document. It would seem that 5 is equivalent to "TYPE_3BYTE_BGR".

Answer (score 4):

It's [TYPE_3BYTE_BGR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR):

```
/**
 * Represents an image with 8-bit RGB color components, corresponding 
 * to a Windows-style BGR color model) with the colors Blue, Green,
 * and Red stored in 3 bytes.  There is no alpha.  The image has a
 * <code>ComponentColorModel</code>.
 * When data with non-opaque alpha is stored
 * in an image of this type,
 * the color data must be adjusted to a non-premultiplied form
 * and the alpha discarded,
 * as described in the
 * {@link java.awt.AlphaComposite} documentation.
 */
public static final int TYPE_3BYTE_BGR = 5;
```